# Why do I use load AFTER these portions of code?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, client-object-model

Let's take for example the code below:

```
function createListItemProdus() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('achizitii_produs');            
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('name', some_value);           
    oListItem.update();    
    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededGol), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}
```

From what I've read on the Internet, the `load` function loads the content of the list from the server to the client.

Then why do I use `clientContext.load(oListItem);` **after** `oListItem.set_item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load unless you want to read data.

You can simply `set_item` then `update`. Then when you do `executeQueryAsync` the changes get committed in the back end.

Here is updated code

```
function createListItemProdus() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('achizitii_produs');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('name', some_value);

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededGol), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, can you help me with one more thing? Can I load more than one item? For example clientContext.load(this.newFile) and clientContext.load(oList), one after another?

Comment: Yes basically you can stack using `load` and then `executeQueryAsync` will do all in one shot. This way communication to server will happen only one time.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help, I'll mark your answer as accepted as soon as I can (stackoverflow tells me I have to wait 5 more minutes)